# Use Azure AD to Authenticate Website running on VM

Tags: azure, iis, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine

Right now we have AD set up so access to our App Service is authenticated.  But we need the website to have local access to some special applications.  Since we can't install applications on an App Services, I THINK that means we need to run the website on a VM.

If that's the case, I'd like to not lose the ability for Azure AD to authenticate access to our VM.  I'm sure we can use Azure AD to authenticate us while we RDP to the server, but can it also be used for when we expose our Web Application over HTTPS from the server?

Comment: What does "have local access to some special applications" mean? Are you saying you need a local windows account to gain access?

Comment: My web application, when running in localhost, runs some code which pulls in some dll's which require licensing and such.  They can't just be loose DLL's, they have to be installed in the OS.  So when I pushed to an Azure App Service, obviously their OS didn't have that application either Installed or Licensed.  To license it, you have to open their License Manager on the OS and stick it in, which I assume then writes something to the Registry to allow you to use their DLLs.

Comment: AFAIK there is no RDP available to App Service so since your custom DLL requires user interaction to licence, it would appear you do need to use a VM. Now is a good time to consider whether you really need the custom DLL or whether you can find an alternative provider that has a more modern installation approach. Your vendor might also suggest a scripted way to do this

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @Nick.McDermaid.  Unfortunately, "BTrieve" dbms is not one of those options with any modern installation approach in existence anywhere.  It does NOT Answer this question... but my solution was to run that junk process as a Windows Service, so my App Service just sets a SQL setting somewhere, which is watched and kicks off that Windows Service when necessary, and the App Service in turn watches the results of THAT process, and then uses those results.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could document your solution in an answer for any other poor souls that need to use Btrieve

Comment: Answering my own question is not beneath me.  But I don't have an answer.  My situation is the equivalent of asking how to get to the movies, but not knowing how, so just staying home and playing WoW.  Playing WoW is not how you get to the movies.  Likewise, refactoring your code to avoid moving hosting location isn't an answer to how to get Azure AD to automatically Authenticate a VM hosted site just like it does an AppService.

Answer (score 0):

> Since we can't install applications on an App Services, I THINK that
>   means we need to run the website on a VM

Even though a VM is the simplest one, you do have other options to at least consider. Here is Microsoft's documentation comparing the various options along with scenario based recommendations.

**[Azure App Service, Virtual Machines, Service Fabric, and Cloud Services comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm)**

**Quick Note**:
Amongst the options discussed, avoid Cloud Services (classic) as far as possible, as they are legacy and on their way out. Also, if you still choose Virtual machine, do consider **Virtual Machine Scale Sets** for better scale and management options.

> I'm sure we can use Azure AD to authenticate us while we RDP to the
>   server, but can it also be used for when we expose our Web Application
>   over HTTPS from the server?

Yes, it can be used even when you expose your web application over HTTPS from the server. Exposing over HTTPS would only involve opening up the port through NSG rules and SSL settings for your application in IIS. This will not impact you ability to RDP into the VM.

Comment: Right, I know AD can still be used for RDP.  I want to know if we can somehow tie it to the https.  Or if, since our app would essentially just be running on iis on a server, we couldn't auto-implement Azure AD

Comment: Ok got it.. I didn’t catch that part from your question. I don’t have an exact setup like that to confirm it for you right away.. but will try it out.